How can I specify args to CMake in a configure task with CMake Tools in VS Code?
I want to set up a task in VS Code to configure the project with CMake.
Sadly I cannot find out how to pass arguments like
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=gcc to CMake within a task.
The IDE reports that "args" is not supported.
Current snippet:
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cmake",
        "label": "CMake: configure",
        "command": "configure",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "detail": "CMake template configure task"
    },
],


To configure a CMake project with specific arguments in Visual Studio Code, you can use a shell task instead of the built-in CMake task.
Please read this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode

For your specific question, regarding the compiler choice, I wonder if you can achieve what you want via the "preset" option, i.e., "preset": "${command:cmake.activeConfigurePresetName}"

If should honour the cmake.configureArgs setting, and arguments specified in the selected configure preset (see the preset property of the cmake task type's schema), such as arguments for cache variables in the cacheVariables configure preset property, or other properties for corresponding commandline arguments.

Thank you.
After thinking about I enlarged my already available makefile with a new target to configure CMake. Maybe not the cleanest but a fest working solution.
